# Admob and placeplay integration with android application

Tags: android, admob

Hi Guys i have been searching for the possibility of integrating admob and placeplay into my android application. Already i have admob integrated and want placeplay's ad service to be integrated into my app as well. But i don't have any idea going about it. Anybody as done it earlier please let me know your ideas and thought about it. Hoping for better response. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

They have a sample application for that. 
Check /Samples/PlacePlayAdsAdmobMediationSample

Comment: Yes i have checked that but i never got any ads from placeplay. Also i dont see them link the ad to the particular view. In that class they have allotted a space for admob ads only.